# Is there any C++ XSLT library?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xslt

I want to transform an XSD Document into XML Document(Template), is there any  C++ XSLT library?

Answer (score 7):

[Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/) might fit (I do not know all the features, but it is a reliable XSLT C++ transformation library).

Answer (score 2):

Outside of Windows I've mostly used Xalan. There is also [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/index.html), which has C++ bindings, and [XQilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage), which is built on Apache's Xerces-C library. On Windows, I've used mostly [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(VS.85).aspx), but it is based on COM.

Comment: You happen to have done this on windows outside of VS? Maybe with another IDE and or GCC?

Comment: @Dan Yes, it was GCC on Linux. I used VI, but I suppose Eclipse with GCC could be a viable option

Comment: For the life of me I can’t get MSXML to load the xml using GCC in Codeblocks IDE. I SEEM to have located all the libraries and headers but I error on the uuidof when loading the XML. The compiler says _GUID const&__mingw_uuid<DOMDocument> undefined reference when I use __uuidof(DOMDocument). Care to share a snippet of the your CoCreateInstance function call for GCC? My only other option is maybe to write a VBScript and call it, which I don’t really want to do. I know what you’re going to say, “start a new question”. Working on it just hoping to circumvent it all.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I thought you were referring to non Windows environments. On windows I've only used VS with MSXML. Why not use VS? Even the community edition would be fine.

Comment: Can’t. Stand alone, non-networked computer. Multiple company policy/MOU that machine will never be connected to the Internet. If you do know anyone that got MSXML going in Codeblocks/gcc let me know.