# How to transform XML and XSLT using Visual C++ 6

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, unmanaged

I have to admit that I'm still using Visual C++ 6 and don't plan to upgrade any time soon due to the complexity of the project I'm working on.

Can anyone provide me an example to transform XML data with XSLT stylesheet using Visual C++ 6 in unmanaged code? If this old workhorse doesn't have that feature, which component is considered to be the best in the market?

Comment: Visual C++ 6 doesn't support .NET (managed/unmanaged) code anyway right? What about using XSLT via calling an appropriate XSLT processor directly using system() call or s.th. similar? Could you be a bit more elaborate about your exact requirements please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Windows apps one XSLT processor to use is the COM object as part of the [MSXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms767700%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (I have used early versions of this with VS6 but as it is COM I can't see why this will not work with the latest version)

You can also use pure C/C++ libraries such as [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/) or [Aribica](https://github.com/jezhiggins/arabica)

Comment: Saxon also is a good XSLT implementation, not completely free but may be a good choice if XSLT 2.0 implementation is nessecary. That's beyond MS's XSLT implementation AFAIK. And of course one can use the MSXML SDK COM components if this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Selected MSXML SDK! Javascript can also render!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the answers to this SO question: ['Is there any C++ XSLT library?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941798/is-there-any-c-xslt-library).

[Apache Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/) looks to be appropriate, though I have no personal experience with this lib.

Another option is to run the XSLT processor (executable) directly from your program via `system()` call or similar mechanism.

If you really need a COM component to achieve what you want, you might consider to wrap one of these solutions in your own COM component implementation.